# SharePoint site space usage (limited admin access)

Tags: 2007, space-usage

I would like to find out how much space my group's SharePoint site uses or at least how much its document libraries use (files + version history). However, I am only a site administrator (**not** site collection or farm administrator). I'm interested in the total, but usage per individual file is also fine.

I've googled everything I could think of but couldn't find much that would help. SharePoint programming seems out of the question since I don't have access to the machine. SharePoint Web Services looked promising but none of the services provided seem to give me what I need. I also found a VBA library that lets me list the versions of a document: Office.DocumentLibraryVersion. However, this type does not include a "size" property - why not?

I previously asked this same question on Stack Overflow without any satisfactory responses (I am almost cross-posting, in fact). I have recently installed SharePoint Designer and messed around with it, and while the reports it provides are pretty cool, site usage still includes the sum of only the current versions of files.

Anyway, I would be happy with either of the following solutions:

- A library or API to be used from VBA, VB, or C# (or any other language, for that matter)
- A SharePoint Web Service that provides file size/space usage information
- Some SharePoint Designer reporting option that I missed or a way to create custom reports
- A crazy script that uses http to iterate through all the folders/files/versions in the library, figures out the size of each file, then adds them together and returns the grand total (SharePoint du)

Basically, anything you can think of would help. At this point, even "this is not possible" would be useful. I am currently estimating size based on the largest files, which is inelegant, very imprecise, and rather time consuming.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Please note that I **do not have full administrative access** to the SharePoint installation, so I cannot access Site Collection settings and reports. I am only a **site administrator**.

P.P.S. Just to clarify, if you told me how to find the amount of space taken up by one document library or even a single file with all its versions, that would be more than satisfactory. Furthermore, if you are an experienced SharePoint administrator and are unaware of an easy solution for this, please post so I can stop looking.

Answer (score 3):

Is the information reported using SharePoint Designer (2007) sufficient?  I have been using the properties reported by right clicking on the site, in the folder list, in SharePoint Designer. This gives a report of how many files are in the system and how much space is used.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you want, but have you at all considered just setting site quotas to secure sites staying under a predefined size?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287673.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that's part of the issue, unfortunately. I am only a site administrator and don't have access to these settings. I don't even know what our quota is. We've hit it in the past and recently we've set a limit on the number of file versions in our document libraries to help contain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly I wonder if you're going above and beyond the call of duty trying to find how much space your site is using :) This is something Operations should be able to tell you! It is definitely true that SharePoint doesn't make this easy (to my knowledge), but tools such as [Quest](http://www.quest.com/sharepoint/administration.aspx) are typically used for this kind of reporting.

Comment: That may be true, but I would like to know how much our space usage is improving with limits on number of versions. Operations would be able to tell me our quota but the turnaround on a request is significant enough that it becomes useless to ask for our "current" space usage.

Answer (score 1):

As an Site Owner (and not a Site Collection Admin) you should be able to connect to your site using SharePoint Designer. Once connected, you can click on Site->Reports->Site Summary. This report shows All Files and the total size in KB of all files on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Map your SharePoint document library as a mapped drive, then check the properties of the mapped drive.  It will identify the space allocated, both used and free.

The best way to do this is to go to your doc library, under the connect and export tab, and click open with explorer.  Then copy the path and paste it into a manual drive mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get read access to the SQL database for your SharePoint site, the following link has some SQL querries that can get you the information you are looking for:

http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/QueriesToAnalyzeSPUsage.aspx

-Ron

Answer (score -1):

Recently I had similar requirement,This answer is same as Anders's. But the links in the article also have an option to get the details from code SharePoint Object Model.You can give it a try to see if those API works without quota

Comment: I thought I only had access to SharePoint APIs if I was programming on the server itself. Is that incorrect?

Answer (score -1):

Goto the Site Collection Quotas and Locks page (Central Administration > Application Management > Site Collection Quotas and Locks). Select a site collection and at the bottom they show how much space the site collection is using.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. Unfortunately, I don't have administrative access. I'd like to know if there is a way to find out this information without it.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the Site Collection Usage page. Site Settings > Usage Summary (Under Site Collection Administration). This should tell you how much storage used by the entire site collection and how much your site's quota allows.

Comment: Ha-ha. You're pulling my leg, right? :)

Comment: I was as surprised as you were that no one mentioned it. Here's some more details about it: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262541.aspx

Comment: I am not a site collection administrator, though, so I only have access to the "Site usage report" which shows me page hits by day and the like.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.thesug.org/Blogs/lsuslinky/ssm

It's a free tool to analize the disk space usage on a SharePoint Site Collection.  Has to be run on the server, though, as it uses the SP API.

Answer (score -1):

Please go to the Site Qouta Collection and Qoutas and select the respective site . You should be able to see the size used for an individual site .